Query produces "function unnest(unknown) is not unique error", but is executed fine by the application
I was playing around with composite types in Postgres and Npgsql, and noticed interesting behaviour.
I have a UDT in the db created as follows:
CREATE TYPE ids_test AS (first int, second int);

In addition, there is a table 'test', which mirrors UDT: two int columns, nothing else.
I also have a corresponding C# class 'test_ids' and map it to this UDT. The query is pretty simple:
select *
from test 
join (select * from unnest(@idpairs)) as pairs
on pairs.first = test.firstid and pairs.second = test.secondid

The parameter @idpairs is passed using dynamic params:
    var dynamicParameters = new DynamicParameters();
    dynamicParameters.Add("@idpairs", ids.Select(_ => new test_ids { first = _.f, second = _.s }).ToList());

    var npgsqlConnection1 = new NpgsqlConnection(conStr);
    npgsqlConnection1.Open();
    npgsqlConnection1.TypeMapper.MapComposite<test_ids>("ids_test");

    using (npgsqlConnection1)
    {
        var res = (await npgsqlConnection1.QueryAsync(query, dynamicParameters)).AsList();
    }

Now, here's the part I don't understand. When I grab the query from csv log, I have the query and its params:

execute :  select *
from test
join (select * from unnest('{"(1,1)","(2,2)","(3,3)"}')) as pairs
on pairs.first = test.firstid and pairs.second = test.secondid
parameters: $1 = '{"(1,1)","(2,2)","(3,3)"}'

However, when I inline the param and try to execute the query, I get the 'function unnest(unknown) is not unique' error. Inline query:
select *
from test
join (select * from unnest('{"(1,1)","(2,2)","(3,3)"}')) as pairs
on pairs.first = test.firstid and pairs.second = test.secondid

As far as I understand, the inline query fails because Postgres cannot determine how to interpret the string and requires a cast. However, I don't get why the query from the app succeeds.
Furthermore, even if I add an explicit cast, the result of unnest does not contain column names. The question is, what does the app do to make this query work correctly?

You have an array of composite types. You need to cast the string to an array of that type.
select *
from test
join unnest('{"(1,1)","(2,2)","(3,3)"}'::ids_test[]) as pairs
on pairs.first = test.firstid and pairs.second = test.secondid

db<>fiddle
The log is not a completely accurate representation of what's going on. Parameters are bound as placeholders, they are not injected directly into the query. So the log is just an approximation of that.

Is there any way to get the exact query including casts? I mean, not the approximation from the log.

The exact query is what you sent from your app, except that @idpairs is replaced with $1. You might want to investigate the server options https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT

In that case what I don't get is why the cast is needed when I run the query myself but is not needed when I send it from the app. If the query is exactly the same, then who does the cast when it's sent from the app? If, on the other hand, the cast is not needed, then why is it needed when I run it manually? The only explanation I could see if the parameters actually have a type, which is not visible in the log right now, so the cast is not needed.

The cast is not needed because the parameter is typed as ids_test[] already. It's not a string, it's an actual array that is being passed. When you do it in the query, you are actually giving it a string and relying on implicit conversion, which doesn't work in this case. Like I said, the log is not an exact representation of the query being executed. The wire protocol contains the actual type of the parameter.
